# Switch between databases and perform operations with schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Main objective is to create multi-database system. Here in index.js i've initialized a mongodb connection with test(db). In this orglist collection is present and it holds orgDomain and its database name.
task is to create a object in orglist collection and then automatically create new database from that orglist and switch to that database and use organization schema to insert organization info to the new organization db.

But the problem is orglist is created new database is not showing unless i create any collection in there. and then the organization info should have inserted into newly created db using the schema but it stores in the test(db). I did switch the db but it is not storing it in newdb

this is orglist schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orglistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orgDomain:{type:String, trim:true},
    dbName:{type:String, trim: true}
},{timestamps:true})

const orglist = mongoose.model('Orgs', orglistSchema);

module.exports = orglist;
```

This is organization schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  organizationName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  orgDomain: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  userTyre: {
    type: Number,
    default: null,
  }
},{timestamps: true});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Organization', organizationSchema);
```

And this is the controller function:

```
const orglist = require('../models/adminEnd/niam')
const Organization = require('../models/adminEnd/organization')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

function niamAdminController(){
    return{
        //add organization and its db from niam admin
        async addOrganization(req, res) {
            try {
              // Save org list details in main database
              const org = new orglist(req.body);
              const saveOrg = await org.save();
              //here it is saving properly in testdb

              // create newdb string
              const dbString = process.env.Mongoose_New_Db + '/' + org.dbName;
              console.log(dbString);
              
              //create new db
              const orgConnection = await mongoose.createConnection(dbString, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
              });
              orgConnection.on('open', () => {
                console.log(`Connection  successful!`);
              });

              const db = orgConnection.useDb(org.dbName); // switch to the new database

              const orgDoc = new Organization({
                organizationName: org.dbName,
                orgDomain: org.orgDomain,
                userTyre: 10000,
              });
              await orgDoc.save();
              //but this save() is done in test db not into the switched db.
              console.log('Org info created');
              
              res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                message: "New organization created.",
                data: saveOrg
              });
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: err.message
              });
            }
          }
          
    }
}

module.exports = adminController
```

For what my organization details in second part of controller is also inserted into initial test(db)